# How should i understand that data.key value is always undefined but i can access it with methods like get set or change

Tags: javascript

I simplifying my problem. 
in this code

I try to google it but i do not know how to call it.

```
let data = () => {
    let key = undefined;
    let setKey = () => {
        key = Math.floor( Math.random() * 6);
    }
    let getKey = () => {
        return key;
    }
    let changeKey = (newKey) => {
        key = newKey;
    } 
    return {
        key,
        setKey,
        getKey, 
        changeKey
    }
}

let dataArray = []
for( let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    dataArray.push(data())
}
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log(data.key)})  // **undefined**
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log(data.getKey())})  // **undefined**
dataArray.forEach( data => {data.setKey()})
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log(data.getKey())}) // **rundom numbers**
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log(data.key)})  // **undefined**

dataArray.length = 0;
for( let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    dataArray.push(data())
}
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log(data.getKey())})  // **uff -> undefined**
```

Yep so i hope this is clear where is my understanding problem. 
Maybe it is a problem with my general understanding of JS.
I hope you can help me with that.

Comment: The code is working as expected, what is you actual question?

Comment: why data.key is always undefined even after i use method like data.changeKey(8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integer is not referenced, its instantly used as value. In the moment ther `return` statement is called, the value of your `key` (which is undefined) is copied to the object you return into `key` subobject (which is still undefined).

The `key` inside the function body and the `key` returned are two different objects.

I added example also with objects, because objects value is also copied, but the object actual value is reference, not the object itself.

```js
let data = () => {
    let key = undefined;
    let ourObject = {};
    let setKey = () => {
        key = Math.floor( Math.random() * 6);
        ourObject.key = key;
    }
    let getKey = () => {
        return key;
    }
    let getOurObject = () => { return ourObject; }
    let changeKey = (newKey) => {
        key = newKey;
    } 
    return {
        key,
        setKey,
        getKey, 
        changeKey,
        ourObject,
        getOurObject
    }
}

let ourData = data();
console.log('Should be undefined', ourData.key)
console.log('Still undefined', ourData.getKey())
ourData.setKey();
console.log('Now the value', ourData.getKey())
console.log('int is used by value directly, so it has the value it had when you executed data() and what was in return object at that time', ourData.key)
console.log('However objects are not used directly, their reference is copied and therefore through same reference you can get to the object', ourData.ourObject)
ourData.ourObject = null;
console.log('Still the ourObject variable itself is different than the one returned', ourData.ourObject)
console.log('This is reason the variable was nulled, but object still exist', ourData.getOurObject())
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because `data.key` is set to `key`'s value, it's not reference of `key`

```js
let key = 5;
let obj = {key};
console.log(key, obj.key)
a = 10;
console.log(key, obj.key)
```

But if you pass an object and modify it's entries, you'll see the changes as long as the reference to object remains unchanged:

```js
let a = {key: 5};
let obj = {a};
console.log(a, obj.a)
a.key = 10;
console.log(a, obj.a)
a = {b: 4}
console.log(a, obj.a)
```

Answer (score 2):

What puzzles you is maybe that Javascript passes variables by value, not by reference. You can think there is an exception with objects (and similar, like arrays), but actually it is still by value (the value of the object's reference).

So when you do `return { key, setKey, getKey, changeKey }`, `key` is not really a reference to your variable, but the value `undefined`. It's not updated when you change the local variable `key`.

For your last logs, I don't see where is the problem, you create a new set with `data()`, so there is no reason `key` would be defined here.

```js
let data = () => {
    let key = undefined;
    let setKey = () => {
        key = Math.floor( Math.random() * 6);
    }
    let getKey = () => {
        return key;
    }
    let changeKey = (newKey) => {
        key = newKey;
    } 
    return {
        key,
        setKey,
        getKey, 
        changeKey
    }
}

let dataArray = []
for( let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    dataArray.push(data())
}
console.log('data.key');
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log('  ', data.key)})  // **undefined**
console.log('data.getKey() before set');
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log('  ', data.getKey())})  // **undefined**
dataArray.forEach( data => {data.setKey()})
console.log('data.getKey() after set');
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log('  ', data.getKey())}) // **rundom numbers**
console.log('data.key after set');
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log('  ', data.key)}) // **undefined**
console.log('new set of objects');
dataArray.length = 0;
for( let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    dataArray.push(data())
}
console.log('data.getKey() before set');
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log('  ', data.getKey())})  // **uff -> undefined**
```

here is a quick example to show that with an object, the value of the reference being passed, the updates are reflected, as long as you dont assign a new value to `key`. If you do like it's done in `changeKey`, the local variable changes, but the reference value you returned is still the same, so getting directly `data.key` won't reflect the new assignment, whereas `data.getKey()` will.

```js
let data = () => {
    let key = {};
    let setKey = () => {
        key.val = Math.floor( Math.random() * 6);
    }
    let getKey = () => {
        return key;
    }
    let changeKey = (newKey) => {
        key = newKey;
    } 
    return {
        key,
        setKey,
        getKey, 
        changeKey
    }
}

let dataArray = []
for( let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    dataArray.push(data())
}
console.log('data.key');
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log('  ', data.key)})  // **{}**
console.log('data.getKey() before set');
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log('  ', data.getKey())})  // **{}**
dataArray.forEach( data => {data.setKey()})
console.log('data.getKey() after set');
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log('  ', data.getKey())}) // **rundom numbers**
console.log('data.key after set');
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log('  ', data.key)}) // **rundom numbers**

console.log('changing key with changeKey("boo")');
dataArray.forEach( data => {data.changeKey('boo')})
console.log('data.key after changeKey');
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log('  ', data.key)}) // **not a real reference: you still get the value of object you returned, not the new value**
console.log('data.getKey() after changeKey');
dataArray.forEach( data => {console.log('  ', data.getKey())}) // **getKey returns the local variable so the changes are reflected here**
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of closure in js. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures).

```js
let data = () => {
    let key = undefined; //key variable declared inside function
    let setKey = () => {
        key = Math.floor( Math.random() * 6); //closure over key variable declared inside function
    }
    let getKey = () => {
        return key; //closure over key variable declared inside function
    }
    let changeKey = (newKey) => {
        key = newKey; //closure over key variable declared inside function
    } 
    return {
        key, // when function is called value of key is passed by value to this variable which is initially undefined
        setKey, //function is passed with variable key having closure of key variable declared inside function
        getKey, 
        changeKey
    }
}
```

so when we do `var test = data()`

```
test = {
    key: undefined //value of key is passed not having closure over key variable declared inside function
    setKey, // functions with key variable having closure
    getKey, 
    changeKey
}
```

You can observe this behavior in this example.

```js
let dataTest = () => {
    let key = undefined; //key declared insie function
    setInterval(() => console.log(key)) // closure over key declared insie function
    let setKey = () => {
        key = Math.floor( Math.random() * 6);
    }
    let getKey = () => {
        return key;
    }
    let changeKey = (newKey) => {
        key = newKey;
    } 
    return {
        key,
        setKey,
        getKey, 
        changeKey
    }
}
```

when you call :

> `var p = dataTest()`

`setInterval` will trigger and it will print key every 1 second. Initially it will be undefined because key was declared undefined.
but when you will call `p.changeKey(5)`. You will see `setInterval` will start printing 5. but `p.key will still be undefined`.

P.S.: If key variable was something which is passed by reference like array or object your key would have been same everywhere.